# Constructor does not have a return type, but why this part compiles normally?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, return-value

A Constructors does not have a return type, but I'm wondering why this code part compiles normally  ?

Here's the code sample

```
class B
{
public:
   int c;
   int b;
public:
   B(){c = 5; b = 10; std::cout << "B ctor" << std::endl;}
};

B b = B();                                //  this part ?
std::cout << "a=: " << b.a << std::endl;
// or the same
//B* ptr;
//*(B*)ptr = B();
//std::cout << "a=: " << ptr->c << std::endl;
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: You mean, why can I assign `B b = B();` when B has no return type?

Comment: Constructors are [special](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor has an implicit return type, that is the object constructed by that constructor.

```
B();  // you are constructing an object and not using it anyway
B b = B(); // you are constructing an object and assigning it to variable b, so that you can use it.
```

So, a constructor ends with a `return *this`.

Inside a constructor, you are dealing with an allocated but not initialized object, and you have to construct it (initialize/construct instance variables).
The result of a constructor call (as seen by the caller) is a fully-functional object ready to be used.

Comment: Uhm, you have to differentiate the inside view (what you can have in the constructor body's code) from the outside view (what result is produced by a usual invocation). Also, the type of the expression `B()` is not a reference. It's simply a `B`. The expression is an rvalue expression.